tensorflow>=2.16.2 -> compile doesn't use provided loss function
I am training a model with tensorflow 2.x.
Up to now, I was using 2.14.1 and I had no issue. Now, I upgraded to 2.16.2 (also tried 2.17.0) and the same code doesn't work anymore. The whole model creation works, I can do everything up to the training itself (with model.fit(....)). Once the training starts, tf is complaining that I did not compile my model with a loss function.
However, this is what I have:
model.compile(optimizer="adam", 
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), 
    metrics = all_metrics)

I tried also with the GPU disabled and I have the same issue. I really want to stress out that this is working fine in 2.14.1. I need the new version as I want to use tensorflow probability.
Anyone has an idea on why this is happening?
Thanks,

You need to make a minimally reproducible example, just one line does not tells us anything.

I have successfully executed the code using TensorFlow 2.17 on a sample
dataset. No compilation errors were encountered. Please refer to the attached
gist and let me know if you are still facing the issues
